# How do I get the context and activity of MainActivity in JUnit test cases in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, junit, android-context

I am creating a simple quiz application where the user answers five questions and a result is toasted onto the screen. In my MainActivity, I call the constructor of a questionsMethods class with parameters context and activity.

My question is: How do I get the context and activity of MainActivity in a JUnit test class? I need this because the methods in questionsMethods make use of context and activity.

Part of the code:
MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        questionsMethods myQuestionMethods = new questionsMethods(this, this);
        private String[] questionArray = new String[30]; // Holds text file
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            myQuestionMethods.readWriteFile("listofquestions.txt", questionArray); // Reads from text file into array
```

questionsMethods:

```
public class questionsMethods {
private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private int localCounterForCurrQuestionCount = 1;
    private String[] localQuestionsArray = new String[30];     

    public questionsMethods(Context context, Activity activity) {
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

public void readWriteFile(String fileName, String[] questionArray) {
    int count = 0; // Holds count of array index in which a line is stored
    try {
        String nextLine;
        InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(fileName); // Retrieves and opens fileName
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { // Check if line incrementer reaches the end
            questionArray[count] = nextLine;
            count++;
        }
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        Log.i("Error", "Cannot read file");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    localQuestionsArray = questionArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Robolectric, however your code is very hard to test.
The `QuestionMethods` class is only responsible for business logic and should not depend on Android.

So if you want to make your code cleaner and you want to test `QuestionMethods` properly,
Robolectric should not be used for classes that are responsible for business logic.